# SWRevealController include Log in page - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, menu, swrevealviewcontroller

I am unable to find a suitable solution to this issue in swift. I have implemented a SWRevealController slide out menu via [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/), in which the initial view controller must be an empty view controller. I am attempting to include a log in page, however if i make this the initial view controller, the slide out menu no longer works.

How do i implement the log in page whilst maintaining the functionality of the slide out menu?

Comment: it is possible bro , show the storyboad screen shot '

Comment: create new empty view controller and one menu view controller(Tableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and drop empty view controller in storyboard and set its class to

> SWRevealController

[image]

> Connections:
>   1.Control click from SWRevealController(New storyboard) to Menu select "reveal view controller set controller".
>
> 2.1.Control click from SWRevealController(New storyboard) to Default view controller(initial view controller) select "reveal view
>   controller set controller".

Comment: Thank you! I was trying things along this line but i couldnt get it working for some reason. :D

Comment: @rohaldb. yes buddy i was faced same issue yesterday only. thanks. :)

Comment: I have found my issue! After logging in, if i to my main page via a navigation controller first (by setting the navigation controllers root view controller to be the home page), the button no longer works. Do you know why this is?