# SWRevealController not working with NavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782566/swrevealcontroller-include-log-in-page-swift), i asked about including a log in page with my SWRevealController slide out menu before moving onto a home page. The solution was the following set up:

[image]

However, i need a navigation bar in order to house the button to open the menu (the navigation bar wont cover the status bar). When i insert a NavigationController in the following way, the menu no longer works

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Use navigation controller to Menu and initial view controller only.

Comment: what do you mean ? @AvijitNagare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Navigation Controller` before `Login/Signup Controller`, then in `viewWillAppear` of `Login/Signup Controller`, hide the navigation bar